# Using Django Tinymce outside of admin forms for normal users?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

I have a basic model which I have added django-tinymce HTMLField for rich text editing. This works perfectly in the admin form in the backend like it is intended, so I think I have set up the tinymce app correctly.

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    blogtag = models.OneToOneField('PageInfo')
    blogcontent = tinymce_models.HTMLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.blurbcontent
```

Then I have the equivalent modelform for it in forms.py:

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        field = ['blogcontent']
        exclude = ['blogtag']
```

But when I go to render the form in views.py and show it to an user through the template, the tinymce editor does not load and a plain textarea form field shows up in my template.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        blogform = BlogForm(data=request.POST, instance=my_instance)
        if blogform.is_valid():
            blogform.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/' + url_param + '/')

        else:
            print blogform.errors

    else:
        blogform = BlogForm(instance=my_instance)
```

And in my template just:
    < head > {{blogform.media}} < /head>
    {{blogform.blogcontent}}

How can I use tinymce for all of my non-backend non-admin form needs? Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:
Here's my settings for tinymce:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "advanced",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
}
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = False

TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out how to make the form a tinymce form identical to the admin form tinymce interface that the tinymce app supports natively. Perhaps there is a better way to do it, but I found out if you simply view the source for the admin page that has tinymce embedded in the form field, you can see that the textarea widget of django gets overwritten by the tinymce app by putting a class attribute in the HTML form field. 
So instead of having something like this in your template:

```
  <head> {{blogform.media}} </head> 
  {{blogform.blogcontent}}
```

You can wrap it in a tinymce class identifier to tell the tinymce javascript that is loaded with the header command to wrap the form with tinymce like so:

```
   <head> {{blogform.media}} </head> 
   <textarea class="tinymce"> {{blogform.blogcontent}} </textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would hazard a guess that you aren't including `{{ form.media }}` in the `<head>` of your template.

Django-Tinymce requires very little overhead to get working, so add the above and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, I did try that before and it did not work. I added {{blogform.media}} to the header. I edited my settings.py tinymc config to the original post in case that is where I have went askew. To clarify, the strange thing is that django's admin site utilizes the tinymce editor perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this to the top of your HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

[Documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-requires-standards-mode/)

Best regards

Roel